# How to insert 1960s date into timestamp field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I need to insert a date from the early 1960s date into a  `timestamp` field in mysql. I have a field 'sent_date' in timestamp. Im trying insert '1960-05-18 03:20:00' (in unix timestamp -303684000) but mysql gives me error. How i can insert 60's date? 
My query: `INSERT INTO support (sent_date) VALUES(-303684000)`

Comment: `sent_date='1960-05-18 03:20:00'`  will do it just fine stop messing around with unix time stamps they're not required for anything and just over complicate it all.

Answer (score 5):

`TIMESTAMP` can only used for dates from `'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC` to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC`. [**See Docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

To solve your problem, you could change the field `support` to type `DATETIME`. Just insert the time in `DATETIME` form, then you don't need to use `TIMESTAMP`:

```
INSERT INTO support (sent_date) VALUES ('1960-05-18 03:20:20');
```

Comment: I have fixed your answer.

Comment: @iProgrammer, with this i agree, you can't but a solution is to focus less on the database and more on your application, i don't know what language you use or what application type, but if you provide more informations maybe i can help.

Comment: If your "application" generates a stamp in unix time and you have no way of altering that perhaps a purchased dll or data export then you can always take your unix time stamp and convert it into a mysql datetime format.  I've not actually met a language yet that you couldn't either natively or with a little home made function (vbscript/asp) help convert that time stamp to a mysql datetime format.  Fix your app the db with a datetime data type column will be fine. (only use timestamp column if you want to do current_time on insert)

Comment: Thank you @redaa i solved this problem. i have changed my timestamp field to integer and saved like integer number. To get date i have used function 'from_unixtime' and all great.